# How can I satisfy my RP desire of Knighthood?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

I'm starting into Pathfinder Society and for once have an idea for a character that is mostly backstory instead of class-driven. More than likely cliche, but I would like to roleplay the idea of a young son leaving his home to search for honor and glory. This character would be the second or third son to a minor Lord. His father, an honorable man, raised him to hold honor above all others. Think of Brienne from Game of Thrones in male form.

Class wise, I believe fighter would be best (two handed fighter specifically) but I honestly have no idea of the depth of Pathfinder classes. I did find a third party Knight class, but I am unsure if PFS allows third party and I'm not so crazy about the class abilities anyways.

So, oh wise sages of the Stack Exchange, I beseech thee:

- Can a character become Knighted? Would this grant any boons (such as a charisma boost)?
- Are there any PFS classes that embody the ideals of honor over everything? Paladin leans a bit too far towards the side of good for me. This character would focus on lawful much more than good v evil.
- Along those lines, could I start fighter and aim for any prestige classes that fit the bill?

Comment: Does your mental image include a mount? Does your mental image include casting spells or employing other magical abilities?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I would love to be able to ride a mount a la Chev, however, I'm concerned about needing a mount to be useful and not having the space. I have no idea where our adventures will be. And not really to the spells and magic, but could if needed.

Comment: You could fluff the Leadership feat as receiving a knighthood, perhaps? Or some other class ability or feat?

Comment: Leadership's a rather poor model for that; knights are soldiers, not necessarily leaders or commanders, and all too often were simply expected to run people over. A command role is not automatic.

Comment: True. Any other feat or class ability you can think of?

Comment: Depends on one's mental image of knighthood, really. Are knights defined by their unshakeable virtue? Maybe Iron Will fits. Are they skilled warriors? Try Step Up. There's no real mechanical way to define the difference between knight-in-training and knight.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Cavalier is literally the "I am a Knight" class**

Check it out in the [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/cavalier) - it fills all the various Knight tropes, and isn't...*insulting*, the way some melee classes can be. Be warned that you may suffer from utility problems when it comes to out-of-combat encounters.

**Knighthood confers no non-RP bonuses**

Being knighted is an entirely roleplaying-based event and will not boost any of your character's ability scores or otherwise affect their sheet, especially not in *Pathfinder Society*.

**Paladin Can Work, But...**

I wouldn't suggest it. PFS can be unforgiving about alignment requirements, and it emphasizes Good over Law, which you've stated that you don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, there is an RP way to be knighted and receive some mechanical boons for the knighted char.

Hiding it under spoiler, since planning char development for taking that route will require a meta-knowledge on a specific adventure, which you shouldn't probably use since it may ruin all the fun.

> As of season 8, it's introductory [Quest: Honor's Echo](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9mb9?Pathfinder-Society-Quest-Honors-Echo) allows you to be made a knight of Taldor or be granted a visbarony (by supporting or not supporting a main quest giver in the end respectively). Both options grant some minor situational Diplomacy and Intimidate bonuses, some free valuables (30-ish gp) Knighthood's got an additional skill-improvement boon for one of the future missions your character will go on.
>
> To get the benefit of these boons you'd need to play all six sub-modules (roughly a hour each) in succession. Can do this in multiple sessions, but without going to adventures other than Honor's Echo in between. So you will probably need to find a table that does that or eventually shop around for "who's running quests 1 and 3". Those two are considered somewhat overpowered and some GMs may decide to omit them.

Or, you know, you can decide to GM that whole adventure and receive it's benefits for that.

Comment: Not much point in having a spoiler area, without some indication of what it refers to...you have to look at it to see if it will spoil something for you...maybe a note outside the spoiler text giving some summary of what is being spoiled?

Answer (score -3):

It may not suit all of your needs, and would certainly set the flavour for the character, but...one option would be a Chelaxian [Hellknight](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Hellknight). They do look...well, hellish. They are part of a nation led by Lawful Evil devil-worshippers. But, if you work at it, there is no reason why you couldn't play a Lawful Neutral Hellknight. There are even Prestige Classes specifically for them, like the [Hellknight](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/hellknight) and [Hellknight Signifer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/e-h/hellknight-signifer) (for spellcasters), and neither requires you to be evil, just Lawful.

Comment: These guys won't fit the flavor he's looking for in his character. Plus they're really childishly-written and quite possibly the saddest thing I've seen produced to represent LE in some time. However, the -1 is for that first part; this answer doesn't address the presented character.

Comment: As I said in the answer, it doesn't suit ALL of his needs, but it is a PFS-legal way of playing a Lawful Neutral member of a knighthood. The fluff may or may not suit, but it does tick the boxes of several of his requirements.